# Authorizing in a Xamarin mvvm cross aplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm planning to write an application which will be using Windows authorization. I'm fairly new to this area and would appreciate any help any of you can give.
What I am looking for is a tutorial or simply a GitHub project where this has been done or something similar.
Perhaps some of you have done it recently and could share an opinion?

So far, I have learnt from other sources that it should be done by ASP.NET Web API. Do I really have to use tokens and other such problematic things connected with them, like refreshing them?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/ may help.

Comment: thank you very much